# selenium webdriver does not work with jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, jasmine

I'm trying to write a simple UI test with Jasmine and selenium webdriver.

However, I'm not able to make it work. Below are the environment I'm using:

- **node v6.6.0**
- **jasmine@2.5.2** (installed as global module)
- **selenium-webdriver@3.0.0-beta-3** (installed in node_modules)
- **ChromeDriver 2.25.426935** (in /usr/local/bin)
- **Latest Google chrome** (Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit))
- **Mac OS X 10.11.6** (El Capitan)

The code is pretty simple (in typescript):

```js
import * as webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';

let by = webdriver.By;
let until = webdriver.until;

describe("my suite", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
    })

    afterEach(() => {
    })
    
    it("should work", () => {
        console.log("==========>");
        let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
                    .forBrowser("chrome")
                    .build();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        .then(s => {
            return driver.getTitle();
        })
        .then(title => { console.log(title) })
        console.log("<==========");
    })
});
```

The generated JS code:

```js
"use strict";
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var by = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;
describe("my suite", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
    });
    afterEach(function () {
    });
    it("should work", function () {
        console.log("==========>");
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser("chrome")
            .build();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
            .then(function (s) {
            return driver.getTitle();
        })
            .then(function (title) { console.log(title); });
        console.log("<==========");
    });
});
```

The same code can be run without any problem as a standalone JS (with node):

```js
"use strict";
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var by = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser("chrome")
    .build();
driver.get("https://www.google.com").then(function (s) {
    return driver.getTitle();
})
    .then(function (title) { console.log(title); });
driver.quit();
```

I don't know if there is any configuration required for jasmine to work with selenium. Please help.

> Moving the webdriver initialization to "beforeEach" does not help. If I can make the code work, I'll move it to "beforeEach" and quit it in "afterEach".

Comment: Well does it print any error for you? Or the code generated by typescript doesn't work?

Comment: I actually figured it out. Since selenium-webdriver is async operations, I have to use async flavor of jasmine / mocha APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Since selenium-webdriver is async operations, I need to use async flavor for jasmine / mocha.

```
import * as webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';

let by = webdriver.By;
let until = webdriver.until;

describe("my suite", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
    })

    afterEach(() => {
    })

    it("should work", (done) => {
        console.log("==========>");
        let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
                    .forBrowser("chrome")
                    .build();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        .then(s => {
            return driver.getTitle();
        })
        .then(title => { console.log(title); done(); })
        console.log("<==========");
    })
});
```